# How to set param value in a custom error object with express-validator?

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, pug, express-validator

I am using `express-validator` to validate input fields in a sign up form.  If an input field does not validate, the sign-up form is rendered again.  I am using Pug as the view engine.  The `express-validator` errors array is passed to the render function, and the params property of the error is used to identify which input failed and render a new input field with a red border to indicate it failed along with a message.

This works fine with a `express-validator`'s validation methods, but when I use their custom function, to define my own validation rule, I do not know how to set the params property value, and cannot apply the conditional CSS class to render the input field with a red border.

For simplicity I will use only the username field in the following example.
The username should fail validation if it is empty, uses non-alphanumeric characters, or is in the database (mongodb) already.  I use `express-validator` methods to test if it is empty and uses alphanumeric characters, and a custom method to test if the username is in the database already.

The problem is, that in the custom method, were I reject the promise with the message 'That username has been taken', I do not know how to set the param property?  Can someone show how that is done?

```js
//validators.js

const {check, body, validationResult} = require('express-validator')
const User = require('../models/user')

module.exports = [
    //! Check username (This works fine and error.param is set to username)
    check('username', 'Please enter a valid username')
    .not().isEmpty()
    .isAlphanumeric(),

    // Check username does not exist in db (this sets error.param to '')
    body().custom(body => {
        return User.findOne({username:body.username})
        .then(user => {
            if(user){
                return Promise.reject('That username has been taken')
            }
        })
    }),
    
    // Check for errors, and if there are render the signup page again
    (req, res, next) => {
        const errors = validationResult(req)
        if(!errors.isEmpty()) {
            
            return res.status(422).render('signup', {
                error: errors.array()[0].msg,
                userInput: {
                    username:  req.body.username,
                },
                validationErrors: errors.array()
            })
        }

        return next();
    }
]
```

Pug

```
form(class="signupform" action="/signup" method="POST") 
    .form__title Sign Up

    label(class="form__label" for="username") Username

    //- If there are validation errors with the param 'username' use the CSS class 'form__input--invalid'
    if validationErrors.find(e => e.param === 'username')
        input(class="form__input--invalid" name="username" type="username" value=userInput['username'])

    //- If there are no validation errors use the CSS class 'form__input'
    else
        input(class="form__input" name="username" type="username" value=userInput['username'])

    button submit
```

CSS

```
.form__input--invalid{
    border:solid 1px red;

.form__input{
    border:solid 1px black;
}
```